# (re)mounting a bootloader device drive, via python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, bootloader, os.system

I am attempting to install a bootloader onto a device. The device is designed to connect as a flash/USB drive and accept the bootloader via file copy. I have to create software in Python to automate this process.

The (Manual) testing process I have used is as follows:

1. Plug in the USB connection.
2. check for a mock file indicating device is ready.
3. copy over the bootloader (drag and drop)
4. wait for device to unmount and remount itself.
5. check for a mock file indicating success or fail/error.

When automating this in Python, during or after step 3 I find the device does not remount, and 'disappears' from the system.

In Linux the device connection appears busy for 30 seconds, then unmounts and the device file under /dev disappears completely.

In Windows7 I tried the 'mountvol' command, but the device unmounts immediately and disappears, the volume description in 'mountvol /l' also disappears.

Also I have been trying with the subprocess.Popen and subprocess.call methods, and the os.spawn*** and os.system methods. Only os.system works on both Win7 and Linux, while Popen, spawnlp and call will report 'file not found' in windows. my process is:

```
args = ("copy", bootloader_filepath, destination_drive)
p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate()
```

after executing line 3, I get the reported error mentioned above.

I want to find a way to tell the OS to rescan for drives, then recognise the correct drive for the bootloader, preferably in Windows7. I need to know what command line utilities and python modules I can use to do this, possibly something in os module I haven't encountered yet?

Also I want to understand how to properly (or at least without errors) use subprocesses like os.spawn*** and Popen to perform file copying, or if an alternative in the os module exists, how to use that?

Any other suggestions are welcome, too.

Comment: What kind of device is this? Is it possible it's crashing and/or rebooting when you write to that file?

Comment: A custom electronic device for a company. I think the main microcontroller is FreeScale Electronics, otherwise this section is outside my expertise.

Comment: Time to talk to the firmware developers, I think. This really does sound like there's something wrong on that end, and you're just managing to trigger it.

Comment: If you do it manually it works? And it also works with `os.system()`?

Comment: Manually, In windows7, it works through drag and drop via the file manager. Manually in Linux, it has the 'busy then no remount' issue I described above.


os.system works at copying the file but then the remount problem occurs. 

I can talk to the firmware developers. Meanwhile If I can get the subprocess methods to work in both Linux and Windows (or at least Windows), that will still help me.